# Where do private, custom bundles live in Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have a number of private, custom bundles that I use in my Symfony projects. Under Symfony 3, they lived in a sub-directory of src:

```
src/
    DSL/
      DSLLibraryBundle/
      DSLTelnetBundle/
      ...
    SiteBundle/      # (or AppBundle)
```

Under Symfony 4, the application-specific bundle is gone and it's unclear to me where my custom bundles should live.

The documentation on bundles (https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#bundles-naming-conventions) provide no specific recommendations for placing custom bundles.

I have tried placing my DSL directory directly under the project directory and under src/. I end up with undefined class errors either way.

I currently have:

```
src/
    DSL/
        LibraryBundle/
            DSLLibraryBundle.php
```

The bundle file:

```
// src/DSL/DSLLibrary/DSLLibraryBundle.php:

namespace DSL\LibraryBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class DSLLibraryBundle extends Bundle
{

}
```

The entry in bundles.php:

```
DSL\LibraryBundle\DSLLibraryBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

Current error when running a console command:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "DSLLibraryBundle" from namespace "DSL\LibraryBundle".

A couple of notes:
- My custom bundles are not installed via Composer
- The actual DSL/ directory will be a symlink once I get this working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update April 12, 2019:
In the end, I took a completely different approach than my initial attempts.
In a nutshell, I now use composer to include my custom bundles.

My custom bundles live in their own directory tree.
Each bundle must have a valid composer.json file defining the bundle. For example:

```
{
  "name": "dsl/base-bundle",
  "description": "Base bundle required by all other DSL bundles",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "authors": [{"name": "David M. Patterson", "email": "dpatterson@example.com"}],
  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "require": {
  },
  "require-dev": {
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4":  {
      "Dsl\\BaseBundle\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

Then define a custom repository in the project's composer.json file:

```
"repositories":[
  {
    "type": "path",
    "url":  "/full/path/to/DslBaseBundle"
  },
 ], ...
```

Then do a composer require dsl/base-bundle
Composer will create a symlink in vendor/ to the bundle and everything works as expected from there on.

My personal library is a regular Symfony project with a lib sub-directory that contains my bundles, each in its own sub-directory below lib/.

The Symfony application provides me with a convenient test bed. Note that the custom bundles must be included in it the same as for any other Symfony project.

@Stnaire, hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not as bad as it's painted in other comments - you can still have your private bundles inside `src/`, you just have to explicitly exclude them from autowiring, so they don't get accidentally loaded with an incorrect namespace.

Lets say you have a `PrivateBundle` in `src/PrivateBundle`.

You set up it's autoloading in `composer.json` like so:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "src/",
    "SomeNamespace\\PrivateBundle\\": "src/PrivateBundle/"
  }
}
```

and in your services configuration (I usually use `config/services.yaml`) do this:

```
# makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/PrivateBundle'
```

If you don't add this exclude, your `SomeNamespace\PrivateBundle\*` classes get automatically loaded by Symfony as `App\PrivateBundle\*`, but contain `namespace SomeNamespace\PrivateBundle;`, so when PHP detects a usage of `SomeNamespace\PrivateBundle` it autoloads them again through Composer, resulting in `Cannot declare class *, because the name is already in use` errors.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 30-Jan-2017:**

Okay. As far as I can tell, Symfony 4 is, effectively, private bundle hostile.

Additional work just kept turning up more and more problems (like getting unit testing to work for a private bundle).

I am currently pursuing other options that won't result in too much additional daily work.

Please ignore my original answer below.

--

**My original answer:**

After some more digging I realized that the classes in my custom bundle directory tree were not being picked up by composer during dump-autoload.

I *think* this is because Symfony 4 is not expecting any bundles except in vendor/.

The solution was to add my library directory to composer.json.

So My project tree now contains a directory for my private, custom bundles.

```
<projectName>/
    assets/
    ...
    DSL/
        DSLLibraryBundle/
        DSLTelnetBundle/
        ...
    public/
    src/
    ...
```

My composer.json autoload.psr-4 entry now looks like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "DSL\\": "DSL/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you have any news on that? I'm in the same case with several private bundles that I reuse in multiple projects, I'm looking for a clean way to keep them while upgrading to sf4.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony4 no longer uses bundles inside the src/ . Bundles are only used within vendor/ as dependencies.

Comment: Yes. That's pretty much the case. You can however, create private bundles that are not in vendor/. See my answer. Thanks.